# Facebook login strangely failing in a page only on a single Chrome instance (mine)

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth, facebook-login

I have an application on Facebook which has two pages, index.php and admin.php.

On Chrome on my Mac, when I open the application it shows index.php without errors, but when I try to visit admin.php it fails to recognize the login, i.e. when I call `/me` I get such an error "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."

It works:

- using FireFox with the same account on the same computer
- on other computers with other accounts, both Macs and Windows using Chrome

I've emptied the cache and cleared the Facebook cookies to no avail, I even tried in "incognito mode". I'm completely clueless: what could ever cause such a localized problem?

Comment: Have you tried Igy's suggestion in the comments?

Comment: @keybored: yes, I also told him it worked, I'm waiting for him to post it an an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that Chrome isn't blocking third party cookies - if so it may be blocking the cookie the Facebook SDK uses to store session info

Answer (score 1):

Try the incognito mode in chrome. It will disable most of your chrome plugins. If it fixes your issue, you can disable one after another here chrome://extensions/ in order to find out which one's the bad one.

Comment: what's "incognito mode"??  Oh! wait... you mean porn mode... gotcha   ;)

Answer (score 0):

The `signed_request` which I assume you are using to extract the information is only passed to the first page that the user visits within your application.
I would recommend creating your "admin" section dynamically (using Ajax calls perhaps) to add the extra UI for administrators.

Comment: I'm not using `signed_request`, I'm just calling a `new Facebook` on each page. Which, I'd stress out, works pretty much everywhere except on my Mac on Chrome. And up to two days ago it worked here too (no idea what could have caused that change, of course).

Comment: Is Chrome set to disable third party cookies? (If so, it may be blocking the cookie the Facebook SDK uses to store session info)

Comment: I don't think the OP would get a notification for this comment on my post. You should repost it on **his** post.

Comment: @Igy: correct! Post it as an answer and you'll win the bounty :)